# Unable to bind autofocus property for an input element

Tags: angularjs

when I upload the login page the button will be gray when I click on the screen the button will turn to blue focus is missing please help me with this [image]
[image]

Html Code:

```
<main id="frontpage">
    <form id="login-form" name="login_form" novalidate>

        <div ng-class='{"input-block": true, "input-block-focus": username_focused, "input-error": login_form.username.$touched&&login_form.username.$invalid, "input-block-disabled":submit_button_value}'>
            <div>
                <label class="labels">Username</label>
            </div>
            <input class="loginForm_input" name="username" ng-model="user.username" ng-focus="username_focused=true" ng-blur="username_focused=false"
                placeholder="Enter your username" type="text" ng-disabled="submit_button_value" required>

        </div>
        <div ng-class='{"input-block": true, "input-block-focus": password_focused, "input-error": login_form.password.$touched&&login_form.password.$invalid, "input-block-disabled":submit_button_value}'>

            <div>
                <label class="labels">Password</label>
            </div>
            <input class="loginForm_input" name="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-focus="password_focused=true" ng-blur="password_focused=false"
                placeholder="Enter your password" type="{{password_type}}" ng-disabled="submit_button_value" required>
            <span ng-click="showHidePassword()" ng-class='{"eye-icon-open":password_visible, "eye-icon-close":!password_visible, "pull-right": true}'></span>
        </div>
        <div>

            <button ng-class='["btn", "btn-primary", "horizontal-center", "submit-button",{"submit-button-loading": !submit_button_value }]'
                ng-disabled="login_form.$invalid || submit_button_value" ng-click="signin()">

                <span ng-if="!submit_button_value">Login</span>
                <span ng-if="submit_button_value" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: I don't understand why all these classes in ng-class - can you try by just keeping "input-block" and "input-error"?

Comment: use only autofocus like  <input matInput placeholder="UserName" [formControl]="userName" autofocus>

Answer (score 0):

As the classes `"btn", "btn-primary", "horizontal-center", "submit-button"` are common, try the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary horizontal-center submit-button" ng-class="{'submit-button-loading': !submit_button_value }"
                ng-disabled="login_form.$invalid || submit_button_value" ng-click="signin()">
```

Comment: are the classes 'submit-buton' or 'submit-button-loading' overriding the color? cz the bootstrap class 'btn-primary' should give you blue color.